# Ruby on Rails: How can has_one be associated with the last child?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

```
Class Item
    has_many :prices
    has_one  :current_price
end

Class Price
   belongs_to :item
   #date the price was set attribute
   #price attribute
end
```

How can i find all the items im selling including (eagerly loaded) the current price (the price which holds the max() date for the given item) in the "current_price" field?

E.g.:

Table Items:

id=1 | name="the_hobbit"

Table Prices:

id=1 | item_id=1 | price=10.99$ | date=2010-01-01

id=2 | item_id=1 | price=12.59$ | date=2009-04-23

id=3 | item_id=1 | price=19.99$ | date=2013-01-03

```
@item = Items.find(1)
@item.current_price # should print "19.99$"
```

EDIT:
I believe my problem is called "**greatest-n-per-group**" but i cant figure out how to do this properly wth a "has_one" association ...

Comment: My suggestion is, When you updating the price for each item, then a item contains many prices and recent price record is used as current price if so then fetch like `@item.prices.last`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the order option on the has_one macro:

```
class Item
    has_many :prices
    has_one  :current_price, :order => "date DESC" 
end
```

Has_one of course will only include one price at the sql level. However if you've already loaded all prices per item with has_many :prices then you can resort to pure Ruby with some enumerable goodness

```
@item.prices.sort_by(&:date).last
```

...which will give you the most recent price.

While I'm at it you should better do this :

```
class Item
    has_many :prices, :order => "date"
    has_one  :current_price, :order => "date DESC" 
end

@item.prices.last
```

since prices are pre-sorted by SQL (faster that way...)

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for another association, just use a custom method.

```
Class Item
    has_many :prices

    def current_price
        return self.prices.last
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use class_name and foreign key for that, also you need sort by date or what you nee, In my case it was version, for your case I wrote created_at field

```
class Item
     has_one :current_price, -> { order created_at: :desc }, class_name: 'Price', foreign_key: :item_id
end
```

And now when you need take latest price of item you need just call

> @item = Item.find_by(id: params[:id]).current_price

And It returns to you lastest price of that item, you can also merge that price with item hash by using

> @item = Item.find_by(id: params[:id])
>
> @item.merge({current_price: @item.current_price})

And output will hash with key `:current_price` and value of the latest related price